# Make a list based on conditions in python to create a unique list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have two lists:

```
a= [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,3]
b= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
output = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

a and b are list of same length.
I need an output array by in such a way that whenever the value in list - a changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 3, A new list should be made in the output list.
can someone please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not for making your homework.

Answer (score 4):

Use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

output = [list(map(itemgetter(1), group)) for _, group in groupby(zip(a, b), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby`, you could do:

```
from itertools import groupby

a= [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,3]
b= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

iter_b = iter(b)
output = [[next(iter_b) for _ in group] for key, group in groupby(a)]

print(output)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

`groupby` yields successive groups of identical values of `a`. For each group, we create a list containing as many of the next elements of `b` as there are values in the group.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler method without using any imports by utilizing dictionary:

```
a= [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,3]
b= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

d = {e: [] for e in set(a)} # Create a dictionary for each of a's unique key
[d[e].append(b[i]) for i, e in enumerate(a)] # put stuff into lists by index
lofl = list(d.values())

>>> lofl
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: Please don't use a list comprehension for its side-effects, use a proper `for` loop. Also, this assumes that the items in `d` are in the correct order, which even if this is true for `dict` in newer versions of  Python, I'm not sure it's also true for `set`.

Answer (score 1):

As you added tag *algorithm* , I believe you want a solution without so many magic.

```
>>> def merge_lists(A, B):
...     output = []
...     sub_list = []
...     current = A[0]
...     for i in range(len(A)):
...         if A[i] == current:
...             sub_list.append(B[i])
...         else:
...             output.append(sub_list)
...             sub_list = []
...             sub_list.append(B[i])
...             current = A[i]
...     output.append(sub_list)
...     return output
... 
>>> a= [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,3]
>>> b= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
>>> merge_list(a, b)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```